Question is closed
ALL,
This is not my question, but I'm curious...
How to support several languages in a wxWidgets based application
The reason for closure - "Update the question so it focuses on one problem only.".
Problem is - it is focused on 1 problem only - how to add i18n to the application.
The fact that it talks about multiple languages is irrelevant.
I strongly believe that this is AI closure... ;-)
Could some one (preferably human being) recheck this?

At the end of the question, we read: "What is the best way to support let say Spanish?". This is usually not a good type of question on SO, FWIW.

@Laf, does it matter what language is there? Its an i18n problem.

Seems the question was rightly migrated.  The main meta is for questions not specific to any one site.

@Igor I meant, asking for "the best way to do X" is not a good question for SO, generally. But, as Daedalus said, this is Meta.SE (Meta for the whole network), you should discussus this on Meta.SO (meta site for SO).

"I strongly believe that this is AI closure.." a what?!

@Laf, I kind of understood. But you also need to keep in mind - the question is about i18n, therefore there is a good chance the OP do not speak very good English or has ESL.

@VLAZ - Artificial Intelligence. The autobot look at the question itself at the end of the post without the context and just close it... But you need to look at the context - the question is about i18n and what to do about it in the wx-based app. Can't do more focused than that. ;-)

You can see quite clearly from the post history that it was closed by three human users, not an AI. There is no such thing as "AI closure" on this site.

@F1Krazy, please read the question and explain why it is not focused?

@Igor I know what AI is. I have zero clue why you think it's used for closing questions. "The autobot look at the question" yeah - no. It was closed by three users. Which you would be able to see in the close notice. So, I still have zero clue why you think there is an "autobot" at play and what made you ever think there was one. The "what" was an exclamation of surprise.

@VLAZ, but then why it was closed? It is a very specific question - about i18n. What is wrong with it? Or maybe I'm just dumb and don't see an obvious thing? ;-)

"but then why it was closed?" because at least three users looked at it and decided that it deserved close votes. There was even a comment where a user said it lacks focus.

@VLAZ, Errr, focus on what? One more time - the OP is asking for the i18n support. What focus/emphasis/accent has to be there? I'm just trying to understand the reasoning, because as it stands right now its not clear.

Internationalization (i18n) is a broad field.  People spend their whole careers working on it.  One cannot describe, in the space of an answer, how to add internationalization to an application.

@RyanM, yes you can. Look at my answer. I just refer the OP to a code sample and the documentation. Simple, straightforward and concise

You didn't post an answer, you posted a comment. Had you posted that as an answer, it would have been deleted as link-only, as link-only answers aren't allowed on Stack Exchange.

@Igor "yes you can. Look at my answer. I just refer the OP to a code sample and the documentation." - Your answer would be 3 answers with the amount of 'content' it has, had you just copied verbatim the content contained in the links (however that would be a copyright violation).

@Daedalus, it would. I just refer the OP to the code sample and the official docs. It is a way to start with i18n and wx.

@Igor My point is your reply to Ryan is false, because you said, "You can" reply to such a question in the space of an answer... But if your answer is 3 answers... No, you couldn't; and if it's just a series of links, it wouldn't be allowed anyway.

OK, so the question like - "Where do I look for a way to implement i18n?" is an OT and will be closed, right? But if I write - "How do I translate the string in my application and use the translations?" will not? Keep in mind - firat one comes from the complete noob in the topic of i18n and second is from the develioper (not a translator).

@Igor No, that second one would be closed too.  As was said earlier, the question needs to be narrowed down; the second one you described would be "needs focus", as per Ryan's point.

Ehh, just focusing on string translations seems focused enough to me. By the way, the ability to interact in comments and edit posts exists to solve this problem: confirm with the asker that that's what they want, edit the post, and then vote to reopen.

Stack Overflow does like to be ambiguous. The help center text that is linked to in the same box states first and foremost "If your question has many valid answers (but no way to determine which, if any, are correct), then it probably needs to be more focused to be successful in our format.". That's a lot more to the point than the dinky "Update the question so it focuses on one problem only" you get in the closure reason box.

@Gimby, this is so crazy it is idiotic. Why not be precise in the rwasoning? Why do I need to click more and more and then scroll more and more to find out what is wrong?

@Igor you ain't seen the full scale of the insanity yet. The full rules and guidelines for SO  are pretty much distributed through oral tradition That's right, you need to read through 15 years-worth of litigation and discussion here in meta. Not something I expect of anyone, new or old, but it is helpful.

@user4581301, you are joking, right? ;-) I was working in Ukraine in 1994 and there was a talk about "no-paper technology". And now the web-site policy are based on the 15 years talk.? Something is really weird happened or maybe I'm too old? ;-)

There's no indication that the OP did any prior research whatsoever on the topic. They're basically asking us to either write them a book or do the whole project for them.

@Igor - “I strongly believe that this is AI closure” - It wasn’t; Real users voted to closed it and downvote it, now suspect AI was used to generate the question, that would explain the close to insulting level of low quality of question that was asked. The “community user” isn’t a bot, it’s more of a script that is initiated based of user’s actions

Community most definitely isn't a bot and has the badge to prove it!

It is textbook "too broad"—i.e., lacking sufficient focus to be answered in our Q&A format.
Although the question does establish the context of it being a wxWidgets-based application written in C++, the question boils down to "How do I internationalize my application?", and that's something that an entire book could be (and surely has been) written about. This simply doesn't fit into our Q&A format because it cannot be reasonably addressed by a single answer.
Note that the very first comment points this out, so there is not really any mystery as to why it was closed.
It might be possible to revise the question to add additional context that would narrow its focus, making it possible to actually answer it, but I'm not totally convinced.


The reason for closure - "Update the question so it focuses on one problem only.". Problem is - it is focused on 1 problem only - how to add i18n to the application.

Yes, and that one problem is too broad. But, you have identified a weakness in the description of the close reason. That can, hopefully, be improved. It used to say something like:

There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

…which is a much more accurate and understandable explanation.

The fact that it talks about multiple languages is irrelevant.

Yes, agreed. It is irrelevant that it talks about multiple human languages. The approach to internationalize would not be dependent on which language you're internationalizing for. But the issue of internationalizing an application is simply too broad to be covered in our Q&A format.

I strongly believe that this is AI closure... ;-)

Thankfully, there is no such thing here.

I really don't like the new (since 2017) phrasing of the current reason - it makes it seem like it's only for questions that explicitly ask multiple in one, and not for questions that are technically standalone but are effectively multiple in one.

@CodyGrey, well described and very clear to put it up. I would argue that the OP did state that everythinfg is in English and they need guidance. However as both of us agree - people can write a book on i18n and still don't cover everything. ;-) In my comment I tried to address the concern of OP trying to point to the sample code and the docs, so hopefull they have something to start with.

And yes - I agree that the old explanation would have been much better and I wouldn't even try to argue or ask this question here.. Thx.

You forgot to add "yet" to the last sentence. I'm 100% sure there will be, and sooner than we think.

I didn't forget. If that happens, I won't be here to see it. Cynically, given the motives of the folks involved, I also do not expect it to happen, but that's a different discussion. @Shadow

RoboMod: The Future of SO Enforcement... But do we get "Murphy" or Mr. "You have Five Seconds to comply"?

I will stick around to see it. Either to watch the world burn, or to be unhappily proven wrong.

I'm not expert in the field (WxWidgets) and not very active in SO, however I believe I can see why it was closed.
The request itself is "support something", but support how? In what way? Is this about translating labels? Text direction? Different controls? I believe the OP should clarify and focus on one of those, then it might be reopened.

when you start with i18n you don't even know where to start, let alone ask proper question. So you start with a very broad one and then try to narrow it down as the answers goes in. Couple of years ago (more like 10) it was completely new. I new nothing about it. I thought about string translation and that it. But working with wx helped me.

Should this question be closed as well, then? Granted, it's an '08 question, so it's probably just been overlooked.

@ipodtouch0218, you can't close the question with the accepted answer. Or could you?

@igor that's forum thinking, not Q&A thinking. At Stack Overflow refining a question is a great idea, but right now the question is NOT refined and should stay closed until it is. At this point any answer it can receive will be overly general, and refining the question in response to answers, that's a no-no because it invalidates the answers. A bit of back-and-forth in comments to improve the question is often necessary, but extended conversations trying to figure out what the question is so that it can be answered is best done elsewhere before the question is asked.

@ipodtouch0218 that question is narrow. It's asking about 2 options. Some folk would close as opinion because of "best", but that a little too pedantic even for me. That said, it's a 2008 question and that was a LOOOONG time ago in this site's evolution. It's not a good question and the answers it received aren't particularly good.

@user4581301, I think you just into the world of "-ism". You just said that the people who has no idea where to start working on something are not welcome here and only questions from the professionals should get an attention. Please think through what you are writing.

@Igor That is not at all what they said.  It'd be more apt to say that SO should be the last step in solving the problem, and not the first; meaning that one should do their research first.

@Daedalus, do you know how many link ae there on Google in regards to such a complex problem as i18n? And if you are a noob in the area you need to know where to start. Especially if you use one specific library/language. Granted - you should try to ask the official channels first, but SO and ChatGPT are the very first in the list - its a human nature to ask questions where it is visible to many people.

@Igor None of that changes my point.  But more than that, please don't stick words in others' mouths.

Igor, the behaviour you are describing is that of a person who would get irate when the biggest, most visible car dealer in town is a Toyota dealership and won't sell them a Volkswagen. This is not logical. Stack Overflow simply is not what you want it to be. I recommend you refresh your knowledge of the site goals, rules, and recommendations. You also seem to view closure as damning the question to hell for all eternity. It is a temporary hold so that issues with the question can be addressed.

@user4581301, "You also seem to view closure as damning the question to hell for all eternity." - first, that was my experience with the closure. Mo matter how many edits I did - it was not re-opening. Second - there are very narrow list of the closure reasons. It should be extended to separate chickens from eggs. And finally - this specific question is about one , however, big, problem - how to properly write the i18n support in the application. Its so complex that trying to ask proper question is even harder than write proper answer.

Also, to answer @ShadowWizard - I believe the OP clearly stated that all text is in English. They didn't specify RTL language at all. His question was how to support i18n, meaning how to make it work.

The short version: if you "don't know where to start", then the right place to start is not anywhere on the Stack Exchange network. That's simply not how these sites work.

@Igor "SO and ChatGPT are the very first in the list". SO is indeed among the first choices if you try to search for an existing answer, or try to research on the topic, but asking a question on SO really should only be done after thorough research. Asking on SO as one of the first resorts is a common misconception, but a misconception being common does not make it right. In this particular case, the user is at least expected to do a thorough search within [tag:c++], [tag:i18n] and [tag:wxwidgets] before asking, and if he has done that, he should have been able to ask the right question.

@Igor If you haven't already, read this answer

@Igor well, Cody nailed it in his answer, nothing to add, it's much better than my answer. But as for what you asked about accepted answer, it does not prevent the question from being closed. You probably got confused with a bounty, which indeed used to "protect" questions from being closed, until recently.
